# What is the probability of drawing a spade again if I already have $4$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

I would like to know how many spades an English deck has, I am confused, the English deck not only contains hearts, spades, clubs, diamonds? I believe that if you know how many there are, the probability that they ask me would be $\frac{\text{the remaining spades cards in the deck}}{48}$. Am I right?

Comment: I'm sure they are speaking of an ordinary, $52$ card deck.  Your formula is incorrect, though, because you have discarded a non-spade.  Thus the denominator should be $47$.

Comment: Not quite right. You forgot that you discarded one card. So, it would be $\dfrac{13-4}{52-5}$. Edit: Ninja'd

Comment: BTW the standard $52-$card deck is known as the *French* deck.  Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck)